# SD card lifespan - few big files vs a lot of small files

Tags: sd-card, storage

Sorry in advance if this is not the right community for this question.

I'm going to write a lot of small files (few bytes each) on my sd card on a daily basis.  I was wondering if this will have a bad impact on the lifespan of the card compared to 'normal' use (fewer, bigger files and overall bigger size than a bunch of small files).

Answer (score 1):

The size of the files that you write to your SD card shouldn't have much (if any) of an impact on the SD card's lifespan.

How many files is a lot? Depending on what you're doing, you may find external storage works better from a performance standpoint, but SD cards are far more hardy than they're usually given credit for.

Answer (score 1):

The main constrain is if you write to the same location of the SD card. And as I understand you question, you arn't writing to the same file and changing the content of the file, but creating many files++++ then it wouldn't be a problem.